# Android Studio cannot resolve any dependencies

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I imported my project from Eclipse to Android Studio without fail and developed for a while. After re-opening my project, now literally all imports fail to resolve in all of my source files.

My classpath seems sane and it cannot resolve any symbol (including Java). All compiler settings seem sane and no amount of cleaning and rebuilding does anything. I also re-imported everything and still seeing same issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What version?  I am having the same issue with a "new project" in Android Studio (0.4.0) downloaded/updated 12/31/2013.